# What is the Communications Port (COM1) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, serial-port

[image]

I recently bought an (old) laptop from someone, and despite having installed virtually no programs on it the Device Manager lists a Communications Port assigned to COM1. Attempting to use COM1 for another purpose brings up a dialogue saying that it's in use and needs to be disabled first, though even when I disable it, I have no luck getting the cable I'm working with to work on that port. What does the Communications Port on COM1 do - what is it used for? And as a bonus, how do I clear it up so that I can use COM1 for what I need to use it for?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you talking to with the serial port (or trying to do otherwise) from the PC exactly when you say `"Attempting to use COM1 for another purpose "` and `"so that I can use COM1 for what I need to use it for"`?

Comment: I'm trying to connect a K+DCAN-to-USB cable to it, where the USB connects to the computer and the K+DCAN cable connects to a car for the purposes of programming it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cable you are trying to use is a serial-to-USB converter.  You would have to install a driver for such a device.  The driver would then emulate a COM port, but these devices are notoriously hard to get working right because USB ports are inherently plug-and-play, but serial ports are not (they existed long before Windows).

If your computer actually has a real serial port on it, then that's the COM1 you're seeing, and of course the software wouldn't be able to use it because it isn't connected to that port.  The driver for the device should be emulating a COM2 or something similar.

If your computer does not have a real serial port on it, then COM1 probably is that device you're trying to use.

Either way you slice it, however, this is a problem with the software for the device not being configured correctly.

Comment: Selected this for best answer purely because it addresses the primary part of my question: what the Communications Port on COM1 exactly is and what it's doing there. I didn't expect to have a physical serial port on my laptop, but I've just checked, and there is indeed a 9-pin port, so I now know exactly what the Communications Port is and what disabling it will do. Suppose I underestimated just how old my laptop is! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that the COM port isn't disabled in the BIOS of your PC. You may also need to configure the COM with terminal emulation software with appropriate settings which the connected devices both use for the communication e.g. speed, parity, data, and so on.

> ### [Serial port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port)
>
> The Microsoft MS-DOS and Windows environments refer to serial ports as
>   [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_(hardware_interface)) ports: COM1, COM2,..etc. Ports numbered greater than COM9 should
>   be referred to using the \.\COM10 syntax.[[12]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#cite_note-12)
>
> <sub>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port)</sub>

[image]

Additionally, you may want to look over [COM (hardware interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_(hardware_interface)) for another basic starting point.

> ### [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_(hardware_interface))
>
> **I/O addresses**
>
> The COM ports are interfaced by an integrated circuit such as 16550
>   UART. This IC has seven internal 8-bit registers which hold
>   information and configuration data about which data is to be sent or
>   was received, the baud rate, interrupt configuration and more. In the
>   case of COM1, these registers can be accessed by writing to or reading
>   from the I/O addresses 0x3F8 to 0x3FF.
>
> If the CPU, for example, wants to send information out on COM1, it
>   writes to I/O port 0x3F8, as this I/O port is "connected" to the UART
>   IC register which holds the information that is to be sent out.
>
> The COM ports in PC-compatible are typically defined as:
>
> - COM1: I/O port 0x3F8, IRQ 4
> - COM2: I/O port 0x2F8, IRQ 3
> - COM3: I/O port 0x3E8, IRQ 4
> - COM4: I/O port 0x2E8, IRQ 3
>
> <sub>[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_(hardware_interface))</sub>

Comment: Is it sad that I can tell that's a Dell C-Series laptop in the serial port picture up there?

Comment: I understand what COM ports are, but I was more looking for an answer as to what this particular default Communications Port does - what it's assigned to, and what disabling it might effect. It was there by default on a fresh installation of Windows 7, and I'm trying to figure out: a) what's using it, and b) how I can safely disable it so COM1 can be used for my purpose. Would it just be as simple as reassigning that port using the Device Manager to COM2, for example, and then assigning the cable that I'm using to COM1?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT; I didn't have an inquiry. I just came across the question and felt old when I recognized the laptop from the picture.  I had one of those in the late 90's  :-)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Latitude#Latitude_C_series

Answer (score 3):

### **What's using COM1:**

As listed in the screen shot on your answer of the **Device Manager**, it appears that **COM1** is assigned to the **Communications Port**.

### **Changing the COM1 device to use another COM port:**

In **Device Manager**, *right-click* on the device using **COM1** and select **Properties**, in the **Port Settings** *tab* select the **Advanced** option, and then you will see a *dropdown* box where **COM1** is listed and you can **scroll down** to another **COM#** which is NOT in use and *select* it, and then *click* **OK** on all windows until you are back to the default view of the **Device Manager**.

[image]

### Additionally:

According to the [K+DCAN USB Interface Driver Installation Manual](http://www.osefactory.com/tools/k+dcan/Installation_Manual.pdf) once you install the drivers on the PC you should then find a new Virtual Comport which you will need to open the **Advanced** properties on within **Device Manager** and configure accordingly from there as per those steps or whatever you can get to work if this isn't the specific cable you have. This is the same area you can specify the COM port to use as well once you free up **COM1** per the previous steps, you can then assign this one to **COM1**.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Unfortunately, it didn't answer my primary question - what exactly the Communications Port is and what it does, hence why I couldn't really vote it as Best Answer. Upvoted anyway for answering the second part of my question in great detail, and for digging up that Installation Manual - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Some mainboards have an integrated COM port. For usage it has to be connected first.

Check the manual of the mainboard.